# Javascript less than that fails when I use a variable for comparison

Tags: javascript, variables, comparison-operators

I have two 'if less then' blocks that don't seem to be working for me when I replace the right hand side of the comparison from Math.PI to my variable, this.bottomChainAngleRads.

**Context:** I'm animating a chain between two gears, and so iterating over the teeth of two gears to hide/show its links as they rotate

Earlier in the code, the variable is initialized with math, not a string.

```
this.bottomChainAngleRads = Math.PI + 2 * Math.atan2(...);
```

Then I want to do something with it every once in a while:

```
this.step = function() {
  console.log('this.bottomChainAngleRads = ' + this.bottomChainAngleRads  // Just over PI. Usually about 3.4.
              + ' ' + $.isNumeric(this.bottomChainAngleRads));            // Always true.

  // Counting the passing through each if block. Expecting a little in each.
  var frontDisplay = 0, frontHide = 0, rearDisplay = 0, rearHide = 0;

  $(this.frontGear.div).find('.geartooth').each(function(index, el) {
    var totalRadians = measureRotation(el);
    console.log('front totalRadians = ' + totalRadians + ' '    // From 0 to TWO_PI
                + (totalRadians < this.bottomChainAngleRads));  // Always false. WTF.
    if (totalRadians < this.bottomChainAngleRads) { // <================ FAILS. NEVER TRUE.
    // if (totalRadians < Math.PI) { // MOSTLY CORRECT, but expectedly off by minor angle.
      ++frontDisplay;
      // .. do stuff
    } else {
      ++frontHide;
      // .. do other stuff
    }
  });

  $(this.rearGear.div).find('.geartooth').each(function(index, el) {
    var totalRadians = measureRotation(el);
    console.log('rear totalRadians = ' + totalRadians + ' '     // From 0 to TWO_PI
                + (totalRadians < this.bottomChainAngleRads));  // Always false. WTF.
    if (totalRadians < this.bottomChainAngleRads) { // <================ FAILS. NEVER TRUE.
    // if (totalRadians < Math.PI) { // MOSTLY CORRECT, but expectedly off by minor angle.
      ++rearHide;
      // .. do stuff
    } else {
      ++rearDisplay;
      // .. do other stuff
    }
  });

  // Below I expected approximately a 50/50 split on each gear.  Instead, I get...
  console.log('front: ' + frontDisplay + ', ' + frontHide     // Nothing, All.
              + '; rear: ' + rearDisplay + ', ' + rearHide);  // All, Nothing
}
```

Sorry for the verbose code, but because I feel I've tried so many things, I wanted to give a bigger picture.

Comment: This is a scope issue. `this` inside the `.each` refers to a DOM element rather than your object. Use `var that=this` outside of the `.each` and then use `that` whereever appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context inside of `each` callback is not your object instance anymore, `this` points to individual DOM elements (`.geartooth`), which obviously don't have property `bottomChainAngleRads`.

The simplest fix is to save correct context reference. Try this:

```
var self = this;
$(this.rearGear.div).find('.geartooth').each(function(index, el) {
    var totalRadians = measureRotation(el);
    if (totalRadians < self.bottomChainAngleRads) {
    ... 
});
```

Comment: Thank you.  I can now stop my head banging.

Comment: You can also use jQuery's [proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to set contexts `.each($.proxy(myFunction, this))`. This is especially useful with event handlers where it is convenient to use partial applications which proxy also handles.